# Запрос к мультимедиа библиотеке в Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, media-library

Здравствуйте! Возможно ли манипулировать файлами (переименовать, переместить, удалить) из мультимедиа библиотеки Windows Phone 8? Как получить доступ знаю: `var library = new MediaLibrary();` , а как управлять не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извините, первый ответ неправильный, пространство `Windows.Storage` ограничено в своем использовании в Windows Phone 8, пытался получить доступ к библиотекам пользователя через: `KnowFolders.MusicLibrary`, но говорит что не поддерживается в Windows Phone. Вернулся к пространству имен `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media`, здесь есть класс `MediaLibraryExtensions` с методами работы с файлами

Answer (score 0):

Метод `var library = new MediaLibrary();` устаревший и использовался в Windows Phone 7.X. В Windows Phone 8 можно использовать пространство имен Windows.Storage для полноценной работы с библиотеками пользователя.